# Visual studio 2010 sql project - how to run?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010

I have a SQL project in my .Net project in Visual Studio 2010. I added it to my solution because I thought it will help me to create all the database objects in more environment without difficulties. 
My scope is to create/define the database objects (tables and stored procedures) in more computers, easily.For this purpose I created an Sql project in visual studio and I added for each table and stored procedure the creation script in this project. Now I have 30 scripts and I'd like to run it on a new sql instance.

If I open each sql file I have, in visual studio, an toolbat that allows me to tun the opened file on a sql instance (I have an connect button) and this generates the proper object (table or SP).

The question is: how do I do to run all the files in this project in one click. How to create all the objects in one click? Now I have about 30 scripts to run, and I need a proper way.

The way I tried to do it was to set as default project the sql project and to press run (F5), but then I got some strange compilation errors in sql files, errors witch didn't was there when I run (execute) each script individually.

Here is the right click menu for this project (No Run, Publish or something else!):
[image]

I tried to use from that menu the Deploy command. The bad news (for me) is that I got this on that command:
[image]

I don't have any error in my sql scripts, each one runs correctly.

Thank you.

Comment: If you have a SQL Server Database Project (SSDT), you can right click on the project and select publish.

Comment: I don't have  a publish command in right click menu. How do I know what kind of project do I have?

Comment: SSDT are the newest database projects.  If you are using VS 2010, you need to install sp1.  I believe the Deploy is what you are looking for.  Select that option and see if it works.  (Its been a while since I used that project, so I don't remember off the top of my head).

Comment: This might help you as well.  http://vsdatabaseguide.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use need to deploy your project onto a database thus use the `Deploy` menu item.

Comment: This is the way to do it: Deploy from the right click menu. The issue is to write all the scripts on the way that visual studio expect this. Visual studio will show build errors for the project if the scripts (sql scripts) contain other instruction except the one that create/modify the tables/SP/etc. I had on my scripts code to check if the SP exists, case I dropped the SP and recreate it. VS didn't love this. The solution is to write only the create block and VS will take care by itself to drop if the SP exists. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @ZelterAdy: Same for me. Initially I had both check, delete and create scripts. But during migration left only create.

Answer (score 0):

The way database projects work, is that they compare the schema in the project to the schema at the destination.

What this means is you shouldn't have an use statements, or alter statements, ect...

What does one of those procs look like that is throwing the error?